# Can't sync time: Time synchronisation failed

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have tried everything and it never works. Last time my time syced successfully was apparently on 01/08/2015 01:00:00

When I press the "Sync now" button it gives me the error `Time synchronisation failed`.

The log file currently has this output:

```
153092 10:02:14.2536415s - ---------- Log File Opened -----------------
153092 10:02:52.0193374s - Reachability:  removing peer time.windows.com,0x9 (ntp.m|0x9|0.0.0.0:123->51.137.137.111:123).  LAST PEER IN GROUP!
153092 10:02:52.0217099s - Association: (Local) 0.0.0.0:123 => 51.137.137.111:123 (Remote)
153092 10:02:52.0217763s - Created reachability group: (
153092 10:02:52.0220482s - 51.137.137.111:123,
153092 10:02:52.0220714s - )
153092 10:02:52.0221197s - Reachability: Attempting to contact peer time.windows.com,0x9 (ntp.m|0x9|0.0.0.0:123->51.137.137.111:123).
```

And this is my config:

```
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)       
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 1 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 360000 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 32768 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: time.nist.gov,0x9 (Local)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The debug syntax is more like: `w32tm /debug /enable /file:C:\path\w32t.log /size:10000000 /entries:0-300`.

Comment: What other things _have_ you tried? I mean, if you really have tried everything, then I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: Well, the command `w32tm /resync /rediscover` gives me the error: `The computer did not resync because no time data was available.`

Comment: The debug command now works and logged. I've put the log in my quesiton

Comment: Using `w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org 2.pool.ntp.org 3.pool.ntp.org"` did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else encountering this problem take a look at: https://www.ntppool.org/nl/use.html

The command that did it for me was:

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org 2.pool.ntp.org 3.pool.ntp.org"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Try connecting your pc to another network or try NetTime

I have 2 pcs and I also suffered solving this bug on both. The idea came from that my pcs are connected to the same network so I tried hosting hotspot from my phone and it worked perfectly.

I tried everything too, and nothing worked. If you are not able to connect to another network long-term (like me neither) try [NetTime](https://www.timesynctool.com/). This is a really low performance app with a full size of 1.92 MB, and if you allow it can run as a Windows service, starting up automatically and syncing your time every 12 hours by default. (And it works on the "bad" network too, so thanks again Microsoft.)