# Automatic time sync is not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, date-time, ntp

I have enabled automatic time sync. But time sync is failing in Windows. Fillowing is the screenshot of the error.[image]

Comment: Did you use an Admin Username or run as admin to set / change the Internet Time?  You need to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't sync time: Time synchronisation failed](https://superuser.com/questions/1528404/cant-sync-time-time-synchronisation-failed)

Comment: Are you allowing UDP port 123 through your firewall?

Comment: @spikey_richie Other post solves the problem. It works on different ISP. Now puzzling things is is the ISP blocking NTP or the Modem provided by ISP needs some configuration change.